# Django allauth + twitter bootstrap, request.user.is_authenticated doesn't show correct navbar

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, authentication, django-allauth

I'm new to django and have a small problem, which I cannot resolve. I use django-allauth for authentification and twitter-bootstrap for front-page. I want to create a page which is different whether user is logged in or not. So in {% block header %} I check it to show the correct buttons. However, I don't get anything(no Home, News, Dashboard and Data) if I'm not logged in, and I see four of them if I log in. Please help!

```
{% load url from future %}
{% load staticfiles %}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   {% block headbootstrap %}
   <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Basic css -->
  <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}twitter_bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  {% endblock %}
  <title>{% block head_title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  {% block extra_head %}
  {% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>
   {% block header %}
       <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
         <div class="navbar-header">
          <!-- Mobile Nav Button -->
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <!-- END Mobile Nav Button -->
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">HumanPulse</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Navigation Links -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <!--Show Home and News -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#News">News</a></li>
            </ul>
          {%else}
    <!--Show Dashboard and Data -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#yourdata">Data</a></li>
            </ul>
          {% endif %}
        <!-- END Navigation Links -->
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                <a class="btn btn-success" type="submit" href="/accounts/logout/" >Logout</a>
                {% if request.user.first_name or request.user.last_name %}
                    {{ request.user.first_name }} {{ request.user.last_name }}
                {% else %}
                    {{ request.user.username }}
                {% endif %}
            {% if request.user.profile.account_verified %} (verified) {% else %} (unverified) {% endif %}

            {% else %}
                <a class="btn btn-success" type="submit" href="/accounts/login/" >Login</a>
            {% endif %}
            {% if redirect_field_value %}
            <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
            {% endif %}
          </form>
        </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container -->
    </div><!-- /.navbar -->
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
 <div class="container">

  <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Navbar example</h1>
    <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
    <p>To see the difference between static and fixed top navbars, just scroll.</p>
    <p>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/#navbar" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
    </p>
  </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->

</div>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
{% block extra_body %}
{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}
<footer>
    <p>&copy; Blog 2013</p>
    </footer>
{% endblock %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}twitter_bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}twitter_bootstrap/js/affix.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}twitter_bootstrap/js/alert.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}twitter_bootstrap/js/modal.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}twitter_bootstrap/js/dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}twitter_bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}twitter_bootstrap/js/tab.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}twitter_bootstrap/js/tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}twitter_bootstrap/js/popover.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}twitter_bootstrap/js/button.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}twitter_bootstrap/js/collapse.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}twitter_bootstrap/js/carousel.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}twitter_bootstrap/js/transition.js"></script>
```

Comment: Instead of `request.user.is_authenticated` just do `user.is_authenticated`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but it doesn't change anything :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo.

It's not "{%else}"; it's "{% else %}'.

Comment: Thank you so much, Joel!:) I tried to figure it out for a day.. Unfortunately I cannot vote for your answer, the reputation is too low

Comment: Also: you might find it helpful to work in an editor or IDE that understands Django templates and colorizes/indents them properly. These kind of things become trivial to notice when they're miscolored/mis-indented.

Personally, I use PyCharm for my Django projects, but there are others out there that would work a well.

Comment: I use PyCharm as well, but still have some problems there, and with indents too, thanks for pointing that! I don't understand why PyCharm didn't show me this stupid typo problem. I'm new to web programming, but did some projects with Java and C. As I remember, Eclipse didn't let me spend so much time on such things by highlighting them. You helped me a lot, really. Have a nice day!